# How to generate in one single object in c#?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am genrating the json using below class which used Dictionary class. However, while creating the json all the added keys and there value coming in different objects. So, how can I get them in one object.
Below is my code

```
public class AdditionalAttributeBlock : Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        public string BlockTitle { get; set; }
    }

foreach (var item in UnitDetails)
{

    additionalAttribute = new AdditionalAttribute();

     // Logic which assign data to additionalAttribute
      additionalAttribute.id = item.ID;
      additionalAttribute.Name = item.Name;

    lstAdditionalAttributes.Add(additionalAttribute);                                           
}

additionalAttributeBlock.Add(item.SubUnitName, lstAdditionalAttributes);

lstAdditionalAttributeBlocks.Add(additionalAttributeBlock);
```

So, this logic generate the json in below format

```
{
"B1":[]
},
{
"B2":[]
},
```

Instead of this I want the json in below format

```
{
"B1":
[
{....}
],
"B2":
[
{....}
]
}
```

The B1, B2 are keys which I am adding into the additionalAttributeBlock class which is inherited by Dictionary class.

Basically It should come in one single object.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Which object are you serializing?

Comment: This is the will be send to api which will produce it in json. I am passing lstAdditionalAttributeBlocks which is of List<AdditionalAttributeblock> type contains the data in Key,Value format

Comment: It's hard to see where `B1` and `B2` are coming from at all, to be honest - or why you're deriving from `Dictionary<string, object>`. Could you please provide a [mcve] rather than snippets? That will help us reproduce what you're seeing already, and experiment to fix it.

Comment: If you’re serializing a list of objects, you will get a list of objects serialized.

Comment: And, following from @JacobKrall, if you don't want a list of objects, make the list of objects a property of some parent class and serialize an instance of that.  I tried duping what you are seeing, and the code and JSON don't match at all - so I gave up.

Comment: You updated your code.  There is still no `B1` or `B2` in it.  But, as a guess, I suspect if you remove the inheritance and make 'AdditionalAttributeBlock' contain a property that is a `Dictionary<string, object>` (i.e., it holds a Dictionary rather than being a Dictionary), you may solve your problem